# How to optimize LAG function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query takes more than 5 minutes to execute as table has a huge number of rows. I'm looking for some suggestions to optimize this query or any other technique to get the record in small chunks.

```
WITH base AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        accountid,
        MAX(filedate) AS closeddate
    FROM
        (SELECT
             ad.accountid,
             ad.filedate,
             ad.isaccountopenflag,
             LAG(ad.isaccountopenflag) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.accountid ORDER BY ad.filedate) AS previousopenflag
         FROM
             EPM.accountreport ad) x
    WHERE
        x.isaccountopenflag = 0
        AND previousopenflag = 1
    GROUP BY
        x.accountid
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    base
WHERE
    CAST(closeddate AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Your query is likely slow because of your `CAST(closeddate AS DATE) = CAST( DATEADD( dd,-1, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )` predicate can't take advantage of indexes - not because of your use of `LAG`. Change your query to use a range predicate without doing any type conversions, e.g. `WHERE closeddate >= GETDATE() AND closeddate < DATEADD( day, 1, GETDATE() )`. Also, your posted query as-is is invalid: your outer `SELECT` is missing columns.

Comment: IAlso, I assume you have an `INDEX ON ( accountid, filedate )` - if not, **why not?**

Comment: Can you push any of the `WHERE` conditions into the lowest level of subquery, next to the `LAG`? We don't know because we don't know what you are trying to achieve? Also why `DISTINCT` what is that gaining you if you have `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Dai I Thanks for your response. Indexing is there for both columns.  I corrected the where condition as you suggested but still it's taking 4 minutes. When I am running the sub query that's it self taking 3 minute that's why I am queuing issue with lag function

Comment: @Mukesh Are they separate indexes or a combined index? With the same column-order? Show us the execution-plan and full `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @Dai both are separate indexes. it need to be combined index?. will share the report.

Comment: what is the timing of this: `SELECT ad.accountid, ad.filedate, ad.isaccountopenflag FROM EPM.accountreport ad where closeddate >= CAST( DATEADD( dd,-1, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )` is that way faster then also including the lag() function?

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell Above query just taking 3 second as we are pulling only previous day record. in the same query if I will apply lag than it takes 17 second. : SELECT ad.accountid, ad.filedate, ad.isaccountopenflag, 
lag(ad.isaccountopenflag) OVER (PARTITION BY ad.accountid ORDER BY ad.filedate) AS previousopenflag
FROM EPM.accountreport ad 
where ad.filedate >= CAST( DATEADD( dd,-2, GETDATE() ) AS DATE )

Comment: *"we are pulling only previous day record"* yes, and isn't that all you need anyway?
Keep adding just one feature to the query then test run  to the 3 second base query until such time as you identify which feature adds the very poor performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution to fix the query. Moved the date convert/ cast separately.

```
DECLARE @dateFileDateMax DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
DECLARE @dateFileDateMin DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))    
My outer query looks like below:
SELECT top 1 *
FROM   base
WHERE  closeddate >= @dateFileDateMin AND closeddate < @dateFileDateMax
```